# Solve for k in the equation $\hat{p_0} = (1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across a paper that stated,

"Given estimates of $\hat{R}$ and $\hat{p_0}$ ... the parameter $k$ can be estimated by solving the equation $\hat{p_0} = (1+\frac{\hat{R}}{k})^{-k}$ numerically."

They later state, "...with $\hat{R}=2.2$ ... and $\hat{p_0} = 13/30$, yielding
an estimate of $k = 0.49$."

My algebra is rusty and I am not a mathematician, so this did not match up with my estimate using R software. Could someone help me understand how they arrived at the value of ~0.49?

Comment: The solution to your problem is given by $$k=-\frac{\hat{R}\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\ln(\hat{p}_0)-\hat{R}\mathrm{W}\biggl(\frac{\hat{p}_0^{1/\hat{R}}\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\hat{R}}\biggr)},$$ where $\mathrm{W}(x)$ is the Lambert W function

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567373/estimate-negative-binomial-dispersion-parameter-k-using-mean-and-proportion-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the solution let us first rewrite the equation to a more "standard" form (I also set $a=\hat{p}_0$ and $b=\hat{R}$ because of writing):
$$a = \left(1+\frac{b}{k}\right)^{-k}\implies a^{-\frac{1}{k}}=1+\frac{b}{k}\overset{x=-\frac{1}{k}}{\implies}a^x=1-bx.$$
Now we can bring the exponent to the other side and proceed rewriting the equation to a product logarithm form:
\begin{align}
&a^x=1-bx\\\Leftrightarrow\ &\left(\frac{1}{b}-x\right)a^{-x}=\frac{1}{b}\\\Leftrightarrow\ &\left(\frac{1}{b}-x\right)a^{\frac{1}{b}-x}=\frac{a^{\frac{1}{b}}}{b}\\\Leftrightarrow\ &\ln(a)\left(\frac{1}{b}-x\right)\mathrm{e}^{\ln(a)\bigl(\frac{1}{b}-x\bigr)}=\frac{a^{\frac{1}{b}}\ln(a)}{b}.
\end{align}
The Lambert W function is defined as solution to the equation
$$x\mathrm{e}^x=y\iff\mathrm{W}(y)=x,$$
thus we get from the equation above
$$\ln(a)\left(\frac{1}{b}-x\right)=\mathrm{W}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{b}}\ln(a)}{b}\right).$$
Solving this simple equation for $x$ yields:
$$x=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{\ln(a)}\mathrm{W}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{b}}\ln(a)}{b}\right)$$
and after performing the resubstitution $x\to-\frac{1}{k}$ (and setting the parameters back to their original form) we get:
$$\boxed{k=-\frac{\hat{R}\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\ln(\hat{p}_0)-\hat{R}\mathrm{W}\biggl(\frac{\hat{p}_0^{1/\hat{R}}\ln(\hat{p}_0)}{\hat{R}}\biggr)}}$$

Comment: Thank you! I am still having trouble accurately implementing this in statistical software (Matlab or R); if you have any insight, that would be great, but that is beyond the scope of this problem and you have helped tremendously.

Comment: Hey! Nice to be able to help, however I'm not familiar with Matlab or R, but the Lambert W implementation is documented on https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/lambertw.html. Also note that you have to use the "-1" branch of the W function

Comment: Henry's comment in the stats cross-post led me to change and undelete my answer. The key is the `lambertWm1` function, which implements a different branch than the `W0` version.